# How to add UITabbar controller and UINavigation bar on UIViewController in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am new in iOS and I am facing a problem regarding to add `UITabbarController` and `UINavigationController` on `UIViewController`. I try code like this

In AppDeleagte.m

```
ViewController1 *news=[[ViewController1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil ];
ViewController2 *menu =[[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
ViewController3 *emergency =[[ViewController3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController3" bundle:nil];
ViewController4 *calender=[[ViewController4 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController4" bundle:nil];
ViewController5 *help =[[ViewController5 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController5" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:menu];
UINavigationController *nav2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:emergency];
UINavigationController *nav3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:calender];
UINavigationController *nav4=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:help];
UINavigationController *nav5 =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:news];


tab=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tab.viewControllers=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav5,nav3,nav4 ,nil];
UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0];
[tabItem setTitle:@"Menu"];
tabItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu.png"];
UITabBarItem *tabItem1 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1];
[tabItem1 setTitle:@"Emergency"];
tabItem1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Emergency.png"];
UITabBarItem *tabItem2 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:2];
[tabItem2 setTitle:@"News"];
tabItem2.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"News.png"];
UITabBarItem *tabItem3 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:3];
[tabItem3 setTitle:@"Calender"];
tabItem3.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Calender.png"];
UITabBarItem *tabItem4 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:4];
[tabItem4 setTitle:@"Help"];
tabItem4.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Help.png"];

if ([Userid isEqualToString:@"null"]) {
        Hard =[[HardSoftScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"HardSoftScreen" bundle:nil];
        nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:Hard];

}
else
{
    ViewController1 *news=[[ViewController1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil];
    nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:news];
    //nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tab];
}
```

when I am using  `nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:news];`

I got output as this

[image]

When I am using `nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tab];`

[image]

I need to call both UITabBar Controller and UINavigationBar Controller at the same time like this

[image]

I also used code like this

```
ViewConroller1 *login = [[ViewConroller1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewConroller1" bundle:nil];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:appDelegate.tab];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:YES];
```

But nothing happen.

So How to do this. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the tabBarController as the root of the window in else condition to get the tabbarcontroller and navigation controller embedded inside it

```
        if ([Userid isEqualToString:@"null"]) {
             Hard =[[HardSoftScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"HardSoftScreen" bundle:nil];
             nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:Hard];
             [self.window setRootViewController:nav];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.window setRootViewController:tab];
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }
```

Comment: it is showing black window. I also need to call viewcontroller1 in else block

Comment: viewcontroller1 is the first tab on your tabbar so it will be shown if you select tab as root. Please add complete code of your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method to get the clear idea

Comment: No I am checking that if userid =null then HardSoftScreen viewController will shown and in else viewcontroller1 will shown.

Comment: HardSoftScreen  is simple view without navigation and tabbar and viewcontroller1 contain both.

Comment: are you using self.window.rootViewController = nav after else condition?